# CSS why is hover only changing background color but not text color?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a calculator program and I'm trying to make it so when user hovers over each button, the background color and text color will change. However, only the background color is only changing and not text color. What did I do wrong in my code?

HTML Code

```
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calculator.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="calc" class="row">
            <div>
                <button class="btn b1">7</button>
                <button class="btn b1">8</button>
                <button class="btn b1">9</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn b1">7</button>
                <button class="btn b1">8</button>
                <button class="btn b1">9</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn b1">7</button>
                <button class="btn b1">8</button>
                <button class="btn b1">9</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS code

```
#calc{
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #909080;
    background: #c7c7c7;
}

.b1{
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #370000;
}
.b1:hover{
    color: red;
    background: #7a7a7a;

}
#buttons{
    margin-left: 35%;
}
```

Comment: Text color is changing to red, its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your style must overlap bootstrap style , so:

**Change:**

```
.b1:hover {
```

**To:**

```
.btn.b1:hover {
```

```css
 #calc {
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #909080;
    background: #c7c7c7;
   }

 .b1 {
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #370000;
  }

  .btn.b1:hover{
    color: red;
    background: #7a7a7a;
  }

  #buttons{
    margin-left: 35%;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
     <div class="container">
        <div id="calc" class="row">
            <div>
                <button class="btn b1">7</button>
                <button class="btn b1">8</button>
                <button class="btn b1">9</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn b1">7</button>
                <button class="btn b1">8</button>
                <button class="btn b1">9</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn b1">7</button>
                <button class="btn b1">8</button>
                <button class="btn b1">9</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: To avoid any troubles it's better to use button.b1 instead of .btn.b1

Comment: awesome that's perfect. I forgot that you needed to override bootstrap

Comment: hi,Liamm, `.btn.b1` have Higher priority than `button.b1`.